# Background position works in pixels only?

Tags: properties, background, position

Hy there
I really dunno whats wrong, i dont get it.
I'm using multiple images for the background body
Looks like this:

```
    body
    {
    background: url('bison.png'),url('ryu.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat,no-repeat;
    background-position:left bottom,right bottom;
    background-size:200px,200px;
    }
```

But instead of showing the images on the bottom, it appears on the top?
Here are some screens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkoM5.png

Now, i used % too. Same problem, lets say 20% 50%, h line 20% and v 50% it should appear somewhere at the middle left part of the screen but it doesn't, instead 1/4 of the img is visible, the other 3/4 is somewhere hidden in top browser section. Instead of pushing it 50% down from top line, it does push it up like 3%?
The only thing that works are pixels and negative % i.e. -50% but why is that?
Can't use pixels because I want that the css responds to various screen resolutions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify some height:

```
body {
   height: 500px;
   background: url('bison.png'),url('ryu.png');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:left bottom,right bottom;

}
```